# What does 方向 mean in this sentence?

Tags: sentence, reading-comprehension

> ありあまるパワーの方向がなんか惜しい子

One character says this over a new colleague at work who really wants to work but because she's new, she's not allowed. So she has all that desire to work but she's not allowed.

Comment: Can you add more Japanese, original context, please?

Answer (score 3):

方向 means the standard *direction*.

- パワーの方向 means just *the direction of power/energy* (or *the direction to which the energy is put*).
- なんか惜しい is the verdict of the speaker about that direction. Literally *somewhat off/wrong*.

The sentence basically says the child is energetic, but in a wrong direction.

Comment: I would like to understand how "the direction of the child's exceeeding energy is somewhat off" fits in the provided context of "a new colleague at work who really wants to work but because she's new, she's not allowed".

Comment: @jarmanso7 The new one is energetic about work, but their energy does not work in the way it leads to high performance. I guess it is more or less similar to *s/he is spinning her/his wheels*